# How to efficiently search large datasets by location and date range?

Tags: algorithm, search, mongodb, search-engine, geospatial

I have a MongoDB collection containing attributes such as:

```
longitude, latitude, start_date, end_date, price
```

I have over 500 million documents.

My question is how to search by lat/long, date range and price as efficiently as possible?
As I see it my options are:

1. Create an Geo-spatial index on lat/long and use MongoDB's proximity search... and then filter this based on date range and price.

   - I have yet to test this but, am worrying that the amount of data would be too much to search this quickly, when we have around 1 search a second.
   - have you had experience with how MongoDB would react under these circumstances?
2. Split the data into multiple collections by location. i.e. by cities like london_collection, paris_collection, new_york_collection.

   - I would then have to query by lat/long first, find the nearest city collection and then do a MongoDB spatial search on that subset data in that collection with date and price filters.
   - I would have uneven distribution of documents as some cities would have more documents than others.
3. Create collections by dates instead of location. Same as above but each document is allocated a collection based on it's date range.

   - problem with searches that have a date range that straddles multiple collections.
4. Create unique ids based on city_start_date_end_date for each document.

   - Again I would have to use my lat/long query to find the nearest city append the date range to access the key.  This seems to be pretty fast but I don't really like the city look up aspect... it seems a bit ugly.

I am in the process of experimenting with option 1.) but would really like to hear your ideas before I go too far down one particular path?

How do search engines split up and manage their data... this must be a similar kind of problem?

Also I do not have to use MongoDB, I'm open to other options?

Many thanks.

Comment: The first solution would definitely work with relational databases (mysql) if you index properly.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing and data access performance is a deep and complex subject. A lot of factors can effect the most efficient solution including the size of your data sets, the read to write ratio, the relative performance of your IO and backing store, etc.

While I can't give you a concrete answer, I can suggest investigating using morton numbers as an efficient way of pulling multiple similar numeric values like lat longs.

[Morton number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morton_number_%28number_theory%29)

Comment: Excellent - that could be very helpful. I will do some investigation. +1 from me.

Comment: This is good theoretical input. However, as far as I understand, a geohash is a Z-order curve, and this is what MongoDB uses for its native geospatial indexing. Re-Building that manually on top of the DB is not a good idea. It also handles edge-cases and offers a lot of search patterns (polygon, spherical, etc.). Since MongoDB does not support bitwise queries, it's probably not really possible to implement this efficiently at all at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think option 1 would be too slow? Is this the result of a real world test or is this merely an assumption that it might eventually not work out?

MongoDB has native support for geohashing and turns coordinates into a single number which can then be searched by a BTree traversal. This should be reasonably fast. Messing around with multiple collections does not seem like a very good idea to me. All it does is replace one level of BTree traversal on the database with some code you still need to write, test and maintain.

Don't reinvent the wheel, but try to optimize the most obvious path (1) first:

1. Set up geo indexes
2. Use [`explain`](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Explain)  to make sure your queries actually use the index
3. Make sure your indexes fit into RAM
4. Profile the database using the [built-in profiler](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Database+Profiler)
5. Don't measure performance on a 'cold' system where the indexes didn't have a chance to go to RAM yet
6. If possible, try not to use `geoNear` if possible, and stick to the faster (but not perfectly spherical) `near` queries
7. If you're still hitting limits, look at [sharding](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sharding) to distribute reads and writes to multiple machines.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment - As I mentioned above I haven't yet tested any of the ideas in real life. However I am in the process of building up the data sets. You are definitely right in that the standard should be followed first and only when this doesn't fullfil expectations, something else should be tried.

Comment: Also one of the insights that all these suggestions have had is that it has prompted me to rethink the structure of the data. Specifically I'm going to look into QuadTrees for generating an id based on date range. This could provide an added benefit of allowing spatial searches over dates. I will also do deeper investigation into how mongo spatial search works. Many thanks again.

Comment: Spatial searches over dates? Quad trees really only work when you have at least two dimensions. A quad tree won't help much for one-dimensional data I think, and a one-dimensional quad tree *is* a BTree. Also note that the MongoId type already contains a date stamp, which improves data locality if that is a concern.